# flushright of theorem captions

Tags: horizontal-alignment, theorems

Is it possible to flushright captions of theorem envrionments? For example consider the following code:

```
\usepackage{amsmath} %
\usepackage{amsfonts} %
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\theoremstyle{definition} %
\newtheorem{au}{testtheorem} %
\newtheorem*{au*}{testtheorem} %
```

And:

```
\begin{testtheorem}[Caption]
Some text
\end{testtheorem}
```

Now I want that caption is printed at the right side of the page.

Is it also possible to remove the period after the caption?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the [ntheorem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) package you can easile create a new theorem style that behaves as expected; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} %
\usepackage[amsmath]{ntheorem}%

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}%
  {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont%
          ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%}
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]%
    \hfill{\normalfont(##3)}\newline}
\newtheoremstyle{nonumbermystyle}%
  {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont%
          ##1\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%}
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\theorem@separator]%
    \hfill{\normalfont(##3)}\newline}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{au}{Theorem} %
\newtheorem*{nnau}{Theorem} %

\begin{document}

\begin{au}[Caption]
Some text
\end{au}

\begin{nnau}[Caption]
Some text
\end{nnau}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, however, if I don't use a Caption I get an error:  LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

Comment: What is the replacement for \newtheorem*{au*}{testtheorem} %
I get:  Package ntheorem Error: Theorem style {nonumbermystyle} undefined (you need it here for newtheorem*)

Comment: @user4011: I edited the code to include the modification that prevents errors when no caption is used.

Comment: @'Gonzalo Medina', thanks for the modifications. I have a further question: What corresponds to \theoremstyle{definition} % (i.e. that the font is not italic)
in your ntheorem solution?

Comment: @user4011: if you want to change the font used in the body, simply add `\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}` right after `\theoremstyle{mystyle}` and before `\newtheorem{au}{Theorem}`.

Comment: @user4011: I just added the code needed for the no numbered version of the new style, allowing you to use `\newtheorem*`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using the [thmtools](http://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) package (plus `amsthm` as backend).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[%
  notefont=\hfill\normalfont,%
  headpunct={},%
  postheadspace=\newline%
]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle,name=Theorem]{au}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle,name=Theorem,numbered=no]{nnau}

\begin{document}

\begin{au}[Caption]
Some text
\end{au}

\begin{nnau}[Caption]
Some text
\end{nnau}

\end{document}
```